# How to compare two variable columns with each other in R?

Tags: r, rstudio, data-analysis

I'm new to R and need help! I have many variables including Response and RightResponse.
I need to compare those two columns, and create a new column that can show whether there is a match or miss between each of the value pairs.
Thanks.

Comment: `df$match <- (df$Response == df$RightResponse)`

Comment: Hi,  this would be a better question if you would add example data and then your desired result.  Preferably do this in a way that someone can copy and past.  @AndrewGustar you should write that up as an an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

> res <- data.frame(Response=c(1,4,4,3,3,6,3),RightResponse=c(1,2,4,3,3,6,5))
> res <- res %>% mutate("CorrectOrNot" = ifelse(Response == RightResponse, "Correct","Incorrect"))
> res

  Response RightResponse CorrectOrNot
1        1             1      Correct
2        4             2    Incorrect
3        4             4      Correct
4        3             3      Correct
5        3             3      Correct
6        6             6      Correct
7        3             5    Incorrect
```

Basically the mutate function has created a new column containing the results of a comparison between Response and RightResponse.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Tamara, if you have the data in a csv format then potentially you can read this file into a dataframe via read_csv which is part of the tidyverse library.
i.e. df1 <- read_csv(your_dat_location)

below is a link all about reading data in R:
[link] (https://r4ds.had.co.nz/data-import.html)

Comment: I just tried  
> res<-data.frame(Response, RightResponse)
> view(res)
and it worked.
Thank you very much!